# regexp to parse grunt comment block with comma separated targets

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like the following regexp to accept comma separated values in its second capturing group:

`<!--\s*process:(\[?[\w-]+\]?)(?::(\w+))?(?:\s*([^\s]+)\s*-->)*`

Currently will properly handle blocks of the form:

`<!-- process:type:target -->`

But not blocks of the form:

`<!-- process:type:target1,target2 -->`

Thanks

Comment: Please put string examples

Answer (score 0):

Gah. got it, don't know why I couldn't figure this out already.

`<!--\s*process:(\[?[\w-]+\]?)(?::([\w,]+))?(?:\s*([^\s]+)\s*-->)*`